# With when.js how can I convert a promise to a Node.js style callback?

Tags: node.js, iced-coffeescript, when-js

I'm using IcedCoffeeScript.

I want to write this:

`User.find(id).always esc done` or `await User.find(id).always defer e, user`

But `Promise#always` is deprecated in `when.js`.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

`Promise#always` is deprecated in `when.js` and will be removed in an upcoming version.

However, `promise.always(onFulfilledOrRejected, onProgress)` is nothing but a shortcut for `.then(onFulfilledOrRejected, onFulfilledOrRejected, onProgress)`. So instead of using

```
.always(handler)
```

You will have to use

```
.then(handler, handler)
```

If may affect your code if you were using inline functions for `.always` as with `.then` it would be better to extract them as separate functions.

**Authors of `when.js` recommend using `promise.ensure` instead of `promise.always`**. More details [here](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/2.5.1/docs/api.md#ensure).

> `promise.ensure` is safer in that it cannot transform a failure into a success by accident (which `always` could do simply by returning successfully!).

I hope that will help.